# How to set DataGridView Rows FontStyle with condition at loading time?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, if-statement, datagridview, font-style

How to change the Font Style of all Rows of a DataGridView based on a  conditions?

My condition is `if Cell Value Equal 0 then FontStyle = Strikeout otherwise Regular`

```
Private Function DetailGridViewSetStyle()
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DetailDataGridView
    Dim dgvInd As Integer = dgv.CurrentRow.Index
   
    For cc As Integer = 0 To dgv.ColumnCount - 1
        If dgv.Item(4, dgvInd).Value = 0 Then
            dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("ARIAL", 8, FontStyle.Strikeout)
        ElseIf dgv.Item(4, dgvInd).Value = 1 Then
            dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("ARIAL", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Only use "Function" if you need to return something, that's not your case, use Sub instead.
- `dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font` will set font style for all your datagrid, you need to set font style from a specify row, then use `row.DefaultCellStyle.Font`

If I understood your question, here's the code that you need:

```
Private Sub DetailGridViewSetStyle()
        Dim dgv As DataGridView = DetailDataGridView

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
            Dim Value As Boolean = CBool(row.Cells(4).Value)

            If Value = False Then
                row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("ARIAL", 8, FontStyle.Strikeout)
            Else
                row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("ARIAL", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
            End If

        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DataGridView is bound to a data source, you may want to format the grid's Rows when the DataBinding is complete.
Subscribe to the [DataBindingComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete) event.

After that, you need to handle Cell value changes, to format the Row based on the value of a Column in the current Row.
Subscribe to the [CellValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged) event.

I'm using a helper method to determine what is the current what is the value of the Cell that determines the Font Style change, what is the current Font of its OwningRow, then change the Font Style to the Style specified if all criteria are met, otherwise, revert to default Font Style.

Note: the [DataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.defaultcellstyle) may be null, since the Row may inherit the Font from the `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle`, so we need to check the [DataGridViewRow.InheritedStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.inheritedstyle) value.
There's an assignment that uses a coalesce expression in the helper method:

```
Dim rowFont = If(row.DefaultCellStyle.Font, row.InheritedStyle.Font)
```

If this syntax is not available in your VB.Net version, use an extended form as:

```
 Dim rowFont = If(row.DefaultCellStyle.Font Is Nothing, row.InheritedStyle.Font, row.DefaultCellStyle.Font)
```

Or do nothing if the current Cell value is null (`Nothing`) or is [DbNull.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull): it can be if the `DataGridView.DataSource` is set to a DataTable, for example.
If you want to interpret null Cell values as `0`, change the code accordingly.

```
Private Sub DetailDataGridView_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DetailDataGridView.CellValueChanged
    If e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
        ToggleRowFontStyle(Of Integer)(DetailDataGridView(4, e.RowIndex), 0, FontStyle.Strikeout)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DetailDataGridView_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles DetailDataGridView.DataBindingComplete
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DetailDataGridView.Rows
        ToggleRowFontStyle(Of Integer)(DetailDataGridView(4, row.Index), 0, FontStyle.Strikeout)
    Next
End Sub
```

Helper method:

```
Private Sub ToggleRowFontStyle(Of T)(cell As DataGridViewCell, toggleValue As T, toggleFontStyle As FontStyle)
    If cell.Value Is Nothing OrElse cell.Value Is DBNull.Value Then Return

    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = cell.OwningRow
    Dim cellValue As T = CType(Convert.ChangeType(cell.Value, GetType(T)), T)
    Dim rowFont = If(row.DefaultCellStyle.Font, row.InheritedStyle.Font)

    If cellValue.Equals(toggleValue) Then
        If rowFont.Style <> toggleFontStyle Then
            rowFont = New Font(rowFont, toggleFontStyle)
        End If
    Else
        If rowFont.Style = toggleFontStyle Then
            rowFont = New Font(rowFont, FontStyle.Regular)
        End If
    End If
    row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = rowFont
End Sub
```